# I can not start SQL Server Browser

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2017

I have all the options disabled in SQL Server Browser and SQLl Server Agent
[image: sql services]

Any idea please?

Regards

Comment: Do you get an error message? Have you checked the logs? Just posting a screenshot is pretty useless here.

Comment: You highlight Agent as well but that's an Express install; Express doesn't support Agent.

Comment: Go to Administrative Tools and check the Event Viewer Application Log.